# Is there away to monitor when a elements disabled attribute is set with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, input

I'm trying to fire a new event I created for when a button is set to disabled state (by another method etc...) How can I achieve this? I want to listen for it when the disabled state changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just call the method from withing the method that disables the button?

```
function disableButton(){
     $('#the-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     whatToDoWhenDisabled();
}

function whatToDoWhenDisabled(){
     Do whatever it is you do;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not necessarily have control of the disablement of the button there are two events you could look into:

> onpropertychange (IE)
>
> DOMAttrModified (w3c)

Comment: With this being said - DOMAttrModified still not supported in Webkit browsers, though it does work in IE9, Opera and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

No.  There is no event which is raised when the value of an attribute changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to stay away from putting the code in the method which is being called just because I wanted to to be a site wide solution....

I was thinking of a while loop that doesn't end and  does this

```
if($('#yourButton').is(':disabled')) {
    $('#someElement').trigger('yourEvent');
}
```

but the issue is that I don't want the JS slowing this page down would this be a issue...